# how to pass query resultset from main report to sub report

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a main report which executes a query.I want that result set values to pass into the sub report.How to do in ireport.
Please give me the suggestions.

Comment: result set values?, pass as parameters? it's unclear what you need

Answer (score 0):

The query in the main report will generate some fields. Create a subreport parameter (for the sub-report from the main report) called "paramA" and pass it the value you wish by setting the report expression as needed using $F{myField} as the expression.

Then in the sub-report create a parameter called "paramA" to receive the value from the main report. See [this](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/514329/pass-field-subreport)